# Unpack byte array from BLE packet

Tags: ios, objective-c, bitmap, bit-manipulation

Im developing an app using `BLE` where iPhone device is the `peripheral`, and will respond to write requests of type `CBATTRequest` from the `Central`.

My take is that this represents a byte array from value of `CBATTRequest` via `request.value` of type `NSData` that I can unpack to read `packet #` etc. **Given the size (octets) and position of each field, how can I unpack and read each value, `conceptually` and `technically`?**. And **how would I go about constructing/packing this same byte array as if I was preparing to send this request?** Since I will have to pack data in the same manner for the response.

Comment: @Codo by the way, when I try to assign a value to `userPayload` via  `response.userPayload = packet->userPayload; ` I get error `Array type 'UInt8 [15]' is not assignable`, still occurs even if assigned value isn't from original packet.

Comment: @Codo Id like to try this but not all values are `UInt8`. `const unsigned char responseData[] = {
        packet->pktNo, packet->ctrlCmd, packet->txPowerRequest
    };`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you receive the data, it's probably in a `CBATTRequest`. The data is contained in a member `value` of type `NSData`. The member `length` tells the length in bytes/octects.

```
CBATTRequest* request = ...;
NSData* value = request.value;
int packetLen = value.length;
```

It then makes sense to cast this to a `struct` that corresponds to the structure of the packet:

```
struct Packet {
    unsgined char pktNo;
    unsigned char ctrlCmd;
    unsigned char txPowerRequest;
    unsigned char uuid[2];
    unsigned char txCnt;
    unsigned char userPayload[14];
};

Packet* packet= (Packet)value.bytes;
```

Note that packet is of variable length. So only part of the `userPayload` is valid. The valid length is:

```
int userPayloadLength = packetLen - 6;
```

Now you can easily access the members:

```
int packetNumber = packet->pktNo;
```

To construct a similar packet, you would approach is slightly similarly.

```
Packet reponse;
response.pktNo = ...;
reponse.ctrlCmd = ...;
int userPayloadLength = 5;
NSData* value = [NSData dataWithBytes: &response length: userPayloadLength + 6];
```

> Bit 4 to 0 set to 0x01 for..

This most likely is relative to a single octect, e.g. to `ctrlCmd`. To test it:

```
if (((packet->ctrlCmd >> 0) & 0x1f) == 0x01) ...
```

`0x1f` is the bit mask for 5 consecutive bits set (bit 0 to 5). `>> 0` doesn't do anything but would be required if the bits were shifted, e.g. for bit 2 to 5 you would need to shift by 2.

A typical UUID is 16 bytes long. So I assume *byte index 13 & 12* refers to bytes 12 and 13 within a 16 byte UUID (as only two bytes are transmitted). The remaining bytes are probably fixed to the base Bluetooth UUID:

```
00000000-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB
```

Comment: Hi, I managed to receive requests from the Central, and print values to the console. I'd like to implement what I've learned from your answer but integer literals are too large to assign to a data type in playgrounds. The `integer literal overflows when stored in an int`. Here as an example of data: `did send write request '<07c10850 04c1abf7 39b4b36c ad9627f8 dc66004c>`. How can I work with this?

Comment: Also, regarding your original answer, Im uncertain why to subtract `6` from `packet length`,  set 5 to `userPayloadLength`, and add `6` again to `value` length. Where are these numbers derived from? As you may notice wrangling bits is new for me so any resources to dive deep into this would also be appreciated.

Comment: 6 is the length of the fixed part of the packet and therefore the offset to the start of the variable part. So the overall length is always 6 plus the length of the variable part. 5 is just an example. n - 6 is used to derive the variable part length from the overall length. n + 6 is used to dervie the overall length from the variable part length.

Comment: *Playground* is Swift only, right? So you are suddenly talking about different code. You better open a new question and add the relevant code.

Comment: No, same code. Was going to convert to swift for playgrounds so I don’t have to re-run the app while testing. That should be possible. When I assign data from example to a variable it overflows. Perhaps I should be treating it as a hex string and define like “0x7c1085004c1ab.....” I know if i use value straight from ‘request.value’ this problem doesn’t arise.

Comment: The *struct* will not work in Swift. The code must be considerably different. I have to see it to understand to problem. So open a new questions as it makes no sense to put the code into comments or massively edit the question.

Comment: Youre right. Im basically trying to convert mock data `<07c10850 04c1abf7 39b4b36c ad9627f8 dc66004c>` to `NSData`, as if it was retrieved directly from write request via `request.value`.

Comment: Codo, thanks for helping thus far, I made some modifications to your answer and edited my question to reflect that. Im still Unsure how to work with values like  '\xc1', and uuid appears to be incorrect as well. any help here appreciated.